# How do I know the memory mapping is successful in OpenCL

Tags: java, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I am new to OpenCL.
Currently I am working on a large one dimension array. The size of the array is around 8 million. The following is part of my code:

```
//allocate opencl hosted memory for input
int[] Counts = new int[8000000];

//get device and create context....

CLBuffer<Integer> memIn1 = context.createIntBuffer(Usage.Input, 8000000);   
Pointer<Integer> a = memIn1.map(queue, MapFlags.Write);
a.setInts(Counts);

//memory allocation for the second parameter memIn2

CLKernel kernel = program.createKernel("gpuScoring", memIn1, memIn2, 8000000, memOut);
kernel.enqueueNDRange(queue, new int[] {8000000}, null);
```

Below is my kernel code:

```
__kernel void gpuScoring(__global int *Counts, __global int *value, int width, int height, __global int *output){

    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    int x = gid % width;
    int y = gid / width;
    int count = Counts[y * width + x];
    if(count != 0){
        //need to do something here...
    }   
}
```

However, the question is that I found I can never go into the true branch of the if(count != 0). I am pretty sure the Counts array in my Java code has some index values which are not 0. Is it because the I used memory mapping wrongly? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After map the buffer, you must write your data there, then unmap it.  You usage are more like create the buffer with copy the host data to it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I have fixed the bug. Yes, the reason is that I did not unmap it after mapping, and I calculated the size of the usage of the GPU memory and the host memory wrong.